# App Store receipt

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I'm getting in App Store Receipt in this way:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                _data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
                break;
send _data to server
......
```

In sandBox environment, I test payment lots of times. I find _data became  larger than the last time. Now _data became 30000 bytes. Is anyone know why _data become so large. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is receipt data. It has to include all the information related to all your buyings. All your in-app purchase information can be found there. That's why when you are testing, new in-app purchase information adding again to receipt and the data size getting increased

Comment: I need to send receipt data to server,but the data  size is too large.Is there anyway to pick out my app purchase information from those data?

Comment: Yes. You can use information from "transaction" argument. It has limited and accurate information regarding your in-app purchase. Send these values to server instead of receipt.

Comment: transactionReceipt? But it was deprecated in iOS7.0,Xcode suggests using [NSBundle appStoreReceiptURL].